# Tag review: emqtt and emq

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [emqttd](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emqttd) was created lately. Since the project adopted the short name of `EMQ` a [emq](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emq) tag might be prudent (synonymized to each other).

> EMQ(Erlang MQTT Broker) is a distributed, massively scalable, highly extensible MQTT message broker written in Erlang/OTP.
>
> Note
>
> Adopt a shortened project name since 2.0 release: EMQ

Source: http://emqtt.io/docs/v2/index.html

Comment: Might be worth mentioning: the current tag is [emqttd].

Comment: @Aurora0001 right, edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose we just burninate [emqttd](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emqttd) and change all the uses of that tag to [emq](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emq). When asking a question, new users will find [emq](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emq) popping up as they type *'emq'*, and the tag excerpt can be edited to something like this:

> For questions related to the Erlang MQTT Broker (formerly emqttd), its operation and the behaviour of the broker/clients.

---

Ghanima has now retagged all the questions under [emqttd](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emqttd), so the tag has been destroyed under the nightly maintenance. In other words, this proposal is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).